# TYPO3 8.7.13 - MariaDB QueryBuilder FULLTEXT

Tags: php, typo3, mariadb, typo3-8.x

```
SELECT name 
FROM tx_snippethighlightsyntax_domain_model_snippets 
WHERE (MATCH(name, description, code, comment) AGAINST ('css'));
```

This query works in phpMyAdmin with MariaDB. Now my "problem" is to adapt this in TYPO3 with QueryBuilder. I don't see any MATCH or AGAINST operator.

So far, my function start with this:

```
private $tx = 'tx_snippethighlightsyntax_domain_model_snippets';

public function ftsSearch()
    {
        $connectionPool = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class);
        $ftsQueryBuilder = $connectionPool->getQueryBuilderForTable($this->tx);
        $fts = $ftsQueryBuilder
            ->select($this->tx . '.name')
            ->from($this->tx)
            ->where($ftsQueryBuilder->expr()->eq(
                MAGIC HAPPENS HERE ?
            )
            ->execute()
            ->fetchAll();
        return $fts;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension Indexed Search in the TYPO3 core uses MATCH and AGAINST in queries.

The following code taken from [IndexSearchRepository](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/indexed_search/Classes/Domain/Repository/IndexSearchRepository.php#L512) should help you building up your query

```
    $searchBoolean = '';
    if ($searchData['searchBoolean']) {
        $searchBoolean = ' IN BOOLEAN MODE';
    }
    $queryBuilder->andWhere(
        'MATCH (' . $queryBuilder->quoteIdentifier($searchData['fulltextIndex']) . ')'
        . ' AGAINST (' . $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($searchData['searchString'])
        . $searchBoolean
        . ')'
    );
```

Comment: So it's possible to concatenate **MATCH** and **AGAINST** or anything else needed. That helped a lot !

Answer (score 0):

```
private $tx = 'tx_snippethighlightsyntax_domain_model_snippets';

public function ftsSearch()
{
    $connectionPool = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class);
    $ftsQueryBuilder = $connectionPool->getQueryBuilderForTable($this->tx);
    $fts = $ftsQueryBuilder
        ->select($this->tx . '.name')
        ->from($this->tx)
        ->where('MATCH('
            . $this->tx .'.name,'
            . $this->tx .'.description,'
            . $this->tx .'.code,'
            . $this->tx .'.comment)'
            . ' AGAINST(' . $ftsQueryBuilder->createNamedParameter('put_search_here')
            . ')')
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAll();
    return $fts;
}
```

This one works for me. Thank you !